# One time blink then turn off circuit

Tags: power-supply, 555, blink, cd4017

is it possible to change Circuit Diagram for the following example: http://www.redcircuits.com/Page146.htm or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mrxdiO1b29A

Original: 4 short flashes stay on light

Modified: 1 short flashes stay off light

If it's impossible to change Circuit diagram for my needs, do you have any Circuit diagram for the specified change?

I'm sure there's a scheme for my question, but my electronics knowledge is low. Therefore, I do not know what should be used in search for my answer.

Thanks.

Comment: search for "one shot 555 circuit"

Comment: @dandavis thanks for answer, do you have any circuit diagram for my question or some video example?

Comment: @SmekeriBezPrezimena There are plenty of resources on the internet on circuit diagrams for a one shot 555 circuit. Once you find something and still have a question, let us know :)

Comment: @KingDuken I want the scheme as with video just what original circuit: 4 flash stay on  my question: 1 flash stay off

Comment: @Smekeri: Please don't ask us to watch a video. Post a schematic into your question so the question can be understood without following links which may expire in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to modify the linked circuit as follows.

[image]

Comment: Now I've tried the changed scheme does not work for me. Flashs 2 times and stay on.